# validate decimal with decimal separator and thousand separator

Tags: java, regex

Hi I used this regex for validate number with decimal separator and thousand separator

```
ets = "\\,";
eds = "\\.";
"^([+\\-]?[0-9" + ets + "]*(" + eds + "[0-9]*)?)$"
```

But this `fail` (it accept when it should not) for two of my unit test case,

`12.`, and `1,,2`, anyone can help please?

Note: This work for `1..2`.

Comment: Can you say more? What have you tried?

Comment: Are you considering 1,,2 and 12. As strings you expect to match?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's look at the actual regex that is used:

```
^([+\-]?[0-9\,]*(\.[0-9]*)?)$
```

This matches `12.` because your second part is `(\.[0-9]*)`. Note that `*` means zero or more, so digits are optional.

This also matches `1,,2` because you included the comma in the first character class `[0-9\,]`. So actually your regex would match `,,,,,,,,` as well.

---

This can be solved without regexes, but if you *need* a regex, you'd probably want something like this:

```
^[+-]?[0-9]{1,3}(,[0-9]{3})*(\.[0-9]+)?$
```

Broken down:

```
^ # match start of string
 [+-]? # matches optional + or - sign
 [0-9]{1,3} # match one or more digits 
 (,[0-9]{3})* # match zero or more groups of comma plus three digits
 (\. # match literal dot
  [0-9]+ # match one or more digits
 )? # makes the decimal portion optional
$ # match end of string
```

To use this in Java you'd want something like:

```
ets = ","; // commas don't need to be escaped
eds = "\\."; // matches literal dot

regex = "^[+-]?[0-9]{1,3}(" + ets + "[0-9]{3})*(" + eds + "[0-9]+)?$"
```

Comment: Hi, can you make the comma "," optional as well. This work great for everything except `2000`. It said that 2000 is a not a decimal, but if I put 2,000, then it pass the validation. Thank you very much

Comment: You can add a `?` after the comma to make it optional. In the case of my regex above, use `"^[+-]?[0-9]{1,3}(" + ets + "?[0-9]{3})*(" + eds + "[0-9]+)?$"`

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, 12. matches because you are matching 0 or 1 occurences of (a period, then 0 or more ocurrences of any number between 0 and 9). So you may have a period and nothing in front of it.

1,,2 matches because you are matching 0 or more occurences of any characters between 0 and 9, or a comma. therefor you could have 0,,,,,,,,,,,,,,0.

If you want the last one not to match, make sure you can only have up to 3 numbers before a comma (in the thousand separator) using curly braces to indicate the amount of ocurrences allowed (i. e. {0,3}) after a set of numbers.

```
[0-9]{0,3},
```

@NullUserException just gave a complete regexp that works for your intentions