# Regular expression to match number with Decimal separator and optional Thousands separator

Tags: regex

I need to validate if a number is valid with using decimal separator and thousand separators optionally. I need a regex, because the current code, that is not done by me uses a regex that is not working properly and I am aiming to fix it.

So the following combinations would be legal (Using `.` as decimal separator and `,` as thousand separator)

- 10000
- 100,000,000
- 100,000,000.345345
- 10000.689

But the following wouldn't be legal:

- 10000,000,000.34534

Basically I want numbers with a proper use of decimal and thousand separator or without them at all, but not invalid combinations.
I looked around a lot, so far I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19641268/752842). Which has a great regex that matches perfectly when the numbers have decimal separator and thousand separator, but when I try to add the other options (numbers only with decimal separator, or number integers) I break the expression.

I decided that maybe I could capture groups matching the rules with or, so the number matches one expression or the other like this:

```
^([+-]?[0-9]{1,3}(,[0-9]{3})*(\.[0-9]+)?)|(((\d)*)+?(\.\d))|(\d*)$
```

The first group is the expression from the other post, the second I think covers numbers with a decimal separator and the last one are integers, but it is not working.

For example these numbers are not getting matched:

- 10000000.56
- 10000000

I think the issue it is happening because it always test for the first group, but I am not sure how to use the groups properly so it matches either of them. Also I think I am placing the -+ signs in the wrong place.

I did search a lot, and couldn't find one expression that worked properly. From the ones suggested:

From the [Regex for number with decimals and thousand separator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16148034/regex-for-number-with-decimals-and-thousand-separator) post

- `((\d){1,3})+([,][\d]{3})*([.](\d)*)?`  -> It wrongly captures 10000000. and 10,000,000.
- `^(?!0+\.00)(?=.{1,9}(\.|$))\d{1,3}(,\d{3})*(\.\d+)?$` -> it fails for 10000000
- `/^(?!0+\.00)(?=.{1,9}(\.|$))(?!0(?!\.))\d{1,3}(,\d{3})*(\.\d+)?$/` -> it fails for 10000000
- `((\d){1,3})+([,][\d]{3})*([.](\d)*)?`  -> It fails for -100.03

This [Can I use an OR in regex without capturing what's enclosed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3378773/can-i-use-an-or-in-regex-without-capturing-whats-enclosed) post is not a duplicate, it explains something that could help me solve the issue, but it is not a duplicate, especially because I have issues also with the +- signs. Also my questions covers a problem that is not particular to me, this is a problem many people face, yet from the implementations I have found so far, none work.

From [RegEx matching numeric values with or without thousand separators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6248621/regex-matcing-numeric-values-with-or-without-thousand-separators) post

- `^-?([0-9]{1,3}\.?)+$` -> It fails for -1000 but not for and not for 100.00.3
- `^-?(?!0)(?:\d+|\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{3})+)$` -> It fails for -100.03

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Validate decimal numbers in JavaScript - IsNumeric()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18082/validate-decimal-numbers-in-javascript-isnumeric)

Comment: [This is being discussed on meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/378008/should-i-try-to-get-my-question-reopened?noredirect=1#comment657168_378008)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185445/discussion-between-dzyann-and-jarrod-roberson).

Comment: @JarrodRoberson Suggesting an alternative approach is a good part of any answer, but that doesn't invalidate the question. People need to stop invoking "XY" as a reason to completely dismiss not just a perfectly valid technical question about a thing in a feature, but also the person asking it. Please remember to _be nice_, and remember that you don't have to answer the question if you don't like it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The reason the second alternative isn't matching is because it only allows a single `\f` after the decimal point. That needs to be `\d+`.

Then you need to wrap everything between `^` and `$` in a group, so all alternatives match the entire string.

You had lots of redundant parentheses. And `\d*` in the last alternative should be `\d+`, otherwise you'll allow a number that's completely empty or just a sign.

```
^[+-]?([0-9]{1,3}(,[0-9]{3})*(\.[0-9]+)?|\d*\.\d+|\d+)$
```

- `^` -> start of string
- `[+-]?` -> matches optional `+` or `-` char
- `([0-9]{1,3}(,[0-9]{3})*(\.[0-9]+)?|\d*\.\d+|\d+)` -> whole group 
  has to match `[0-9]{1,3}(,[0-9]{3})*(\.[0-9]+)` or `\d*\.\d+` or `\d+`

  - `[0-9]{1,3}(,[0-9]{3})*(\.[0-9]+)` -> matches numbers with thousand separators and maybe decimal separator
  - `\d*\.\d+` -> matches numbers with decimal separator, and maybe digits before the decimal
  - `\d+` -> matches numbers without decimal separator
- `$` -> end of string

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/rwNIgk/3)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, your expression works almost, but when I use a number like -1000003.65, it fails, but it works for -1,000,003.65

Comment: `[+-]?` was only in the first alternative, it needs to be outside the group of alternatives so you can put a sign before any format.

Comment: I didnt want to bother you, so I edited your question with a slight change. Your regex was matching ".7" as valid, It is because the (\d)*) I changed it to (\d)+). Then I added a brief break down of what the parts do, to see if I am getting it right. If you dont like it please feel free to rollback.

Comment: Let me know if you agree with my changes or if you want to make an update (I didnt update your demo link) and I will accept your answer.

Comment: I thought `.7` should be valid, we sometimes write fractions without putting anything before the `.`

Comment: I agree, I didn't clarify that on my quesiton, either way works great. Thanks!

Comment: There's probably some redundant parentheses, like `((\d)+)+?` could just be `\d+`. It doesn't matter whether it's greedy or not in this case.

Comment: The parenthesis in regex always get me. If you feel there are too many please update it, I just changed your regex the least I could in order to get the desired outcome. I didn't want to mess too much with your answer. But please feel free to update it as you see fit.

Comment: In regex, parentheses are for capturing. If you use parentheses just to help you applying a `*`, a `+`, a `?` or a `{x}`, then it's better to make it non-capturing with the `(?:)` syntax.

Comment: @Cœur That's true, but I don't follow it religiously. If you're just using the regexp to test a string, rather than using the capture groups for anything (e.g. replacement), the extra captures are effectively ignored. There's performance overhead to save them, but it's usually insignificant. The `(?:)` syntax is more verbose and makes the regexp harder to read IMHO.

Comment: @Barmar that's where I wish for some new regex syntax where the default would be non-capturing, and where captures would need to be explicit. But then we would lose the C from PCRE, so it won't happen soon.

Answer (score 8):

You may use this regex for validation:

```
^[+-]?(?:\d+|\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*)(?:\.\d*)?$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/5sLE43/5)

It matches following cases:

- An integer number
- A floating point number
- A number with separators as `,` at 3rd place

Comment: No, it doesn't. It won't work for `100,000,000`, for example, as evidenced by your demo, and fails to validate *loads* of other numbers. This isn't useful.

Comment: Yes, my bad, I made a minor change in the end that broke it. I have fixed it now in answer and in demo. This regex is still shorter & faster, that would cover all the cases mentioned in OP. If there is something not working, please let me know.

Comment: If you also want to disallows leading `0` and trailing `.` you can use this expression: 
`^[+-]?(0|[1-9]\d{0,2}((\,\d{3})+|\d*))(\.\d+)?$`
https://regex101.com/r/GPICKH/3