# Regex that finds both integers, decimals, and thousands separators

Tags: python, regex, decimal

I want to find a regex that matches all the following strings:

```
-5,84;;EUR
2.764,90;EUR
-47;;EUR
```

This regex `-?\d+\,?\d+;{1,2}\s*EUR` doesn't find the `2.` in `2.764,90;EUR`, whereas this one `-?\d+?[.]\d+\,?\d+;{1,2}\s*EUR` only finds the `2.764,90;EUR`.

Comment: because you are matching at least 2 digits with `-?\d+\,?\d+`

Comment: Do you expect all strings to always end in `EUR`?  Could it end in other three letter currency codes?

Comment: Yes they all end in EUR

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Regular expression to match number with Decimal separator and optional Thousands separator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53822997/regular-expression-to-match-number-with-decimal-separator-and-optional-thousands) -- of course you would have to add the match for `;;EUR` but as I understand your problem are the numbers

Comment: Do you want to match it like this? `-?\b\d+(?:[.]\d+)?(?:,\d+)?;{1,2}\s*EUR\b` https://regex101.com/r/eU2Ixz/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
-?[\d.]+(?:\,\d+)?;{1,2}\s*EUR
```

#### [Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/7B7ve7/1)

Comment: Thanks Gilles, but it still misses the "2.".

Comment: Fixed. Try again